# How to connect monitor to usb c without DP Alt mode?

Tags: video, usb

I bought a notebook that have a USB C port. I thought that this port could be used to connect my monitor!
I tried to use a conventional USB C docking station in it, but doesn't work!
After this, I looked up at the User Guide and discovered that this USB C port doesn't support DP Alt mode.

Is there a way or product that to connect multiple monitors on a port without Display Port Alt mode?

I tried a conventional USB C docking station and searched the problem in the internet, but did not find any solution.